# Replacing struct with interface constructor question

Tags: go, interface

I have this sample code:

```
// scene.go

var (
  animal *Dog
)

func Init() {
  animal = NewDog()
}

// dog.go

typedef Dog struct {
  name string
}

func (d *Dog) Attack() {}

func NewDog() *Dog {
 dog := new(Dog)
 retutn dog
}
```

And I want to implement Cat with same public interface as Dog, distinguishing Animal interface

```
// animal.go -- new file
type Animal interface {
  Attack()
}

// scene.go
var (
  animal *Animal // was *Dog
)

// dog.go

typedef Dog struct {
  Animal // added 
  name string
}

func (d *Dog) Attack() {}

func NewDog() *Animal { // changed *Dog to *Animal
 dog := new(Dog)
 return dog
}
```

But in this case I get error

```
cannot use dog (variable of type *Dog) as *Animal value in return statement: *Dog does not implement *Animal (type *Animal is pointer to interface, not interface)
```

What am I doing wrong and how I should do this ?

Comment: As per the error " *Animal is pointer to interface"; change `var animal *Animal` to `var animal Animal`. You rarely need a pointer to an interface; the [faq](https://go.dev/doc/faq#pointer_to_interface) states "Pointers to interface values arise only in rare, tricky situations...". [This](https://go.dev/play/p/BbpRTNTCa7D) might help (there are a number of other issues with your code, such as the use of `typedef`).

Comment: It is a simple rule of thumb; never create a pointer to an interface. The interface takes care of that for you so you'd be creating a pointer to a pointer. Unfortunately the error message you get is not the most enlightening, coming from a Java and Rust environment myself it took me a few days to wrap my head around it. This and how Go by default copies values are probably the two biggest gotchas of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use interfaces and structs to represent animals like dogs and cats, and you want to define a common interface for them. Here are some corrections to your code:

```
var (
    animal Animal // Change from *Animal to Animal
)

type Dog struct {
    name string
}

func (d *Dog) Attack() {
    // Implement attack behavior for Dog
}

func NewDog() Animal {
    return &Dog{}
}

type Cat struct {
    name string
}

func (c *Cat) Attack() {
    // Implement attack behavior for Cat
}

func NewCat() Animal {
    return &Cat{}
}
```

This way, both Dog and Cat types implement the Animal interface by implementing the Attack method.

Note:

- Use composition over inheritance in Go.
- Define methods on concrete types to satisfy interfaces rather than embedding the interface itself.
- Return concrete types that implement the interface from factory functions.